# Struggling to gain weight

Tags: weight-gain

Recently I've been trying to gain weight and I changed from a relatively healthy diet to one where I eat whatever I want but I'm still struggling to put on any weight.
I don't currently lift weights but I do train in Muay Thai which includes body weight excersises (push-ups, sit-ups, squats)

I was hoping someone could give me a few recommendations as to what foods I should be incorporating into my diet and also whether certain foods should be eaten at certain times of the day ?
Also I do struggle to find time to go lifting as most free time is spent Thai boxing which I don't want sacrifice so ideally any excersises would be body weight.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Do you do a lot of cardio? How old are you?

Comment: A properly balanced diet from a macronutrient stand point will help you gain weight.  The simple answer to your problem is you're not eating enough based on your total daily energy expenditure.  You have to eat above that number in order to put on mass.  In order to get an estimate of what your caloric intake should be, we need to know a few things to ascertain a starting point.  Height, weight, body fat percentage, and an estimate of how many hours you workout a week.

Comment: Go get MassTech 10 KG

Answer (score 1):

I do a lot of calisthenics myself and see great results, so bodyweight exercises can definitely get you muscle.

The thing about gaining weight is simply, it comes down to calories in vs. calories out. If you do push-ups and eat enough (healthy foods), your chest will grow. Adding in things like nuts will help you increase your size since they contain a lot of fats and protein. Eat these in between meals as a snack.

If you have a hard time eating because you cannot consume big meals that often, you can try to turn some meals into shakes, like put some fruits in a blender and drinking it.

As far as exercises go, there are a lot of push-up variations, you can look it up on google. For shoulders you can learn to do handstands, and later handstand push-ups for more strength.

For legs you can try pistol squats for power, and box jumps for explosiveness. Lunges are good aswell.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would advice you to keep on your healthy diet.  However, in between the three meals a day, add some snack breaks. Make protien your priority, so that you eat daily at least one gram of protien per one pound of your body weight.
Keep  nuts in your pocket, so that you  crash as much as you can (nuts are rich in calories plus healthy). Try to drink your calories, so instead of drinking water, you may replace three cups of water by three cups of milk a day.  Try too eat five fruits a day, like : Avocado, banana, sweet potato, grapes,... .  Dried fruits are also a good source of calories.

Hope this helps, and you achieve results quickly!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to eat relatively soon after your workouts as your muscles are starved for nutrients from the physical exertion. This is usually the best time to have a high protein shake to really feed the muscles.